# Userfaultfd not working with Android apps?

Tags: android, memory-management, linux-kernel, android-ndk

I am experimenting with `userfaultfd` and tracking memory accesses.

I discovered `userfaultfd` fairly recently and decided to write a simple C program on desktop to familiarize myself with the mechanism. When I got it doing what I wanted I ndk-build an Android executable and tried it out on an adb shell where I see that it is working as expected.

Then I introduced `userfaultfd` in a C++ library where I want to track page faults. The library is basically a Vulkan layer and runs on desktop and on Android. On Android it is loaded by the Android Vulkan loader, when the a Vulkan app is executed and the layer is enabled.

My problem is that, while the desktop C++ library works as expected, on Android I see that the `userfaultfd` mechanism is not working as expected. It seems that the faults are not detected/trapped. The faulting threat doesn't get halted and the handler thread never gets notified about changes on the file descriptor (have tried with both `poll()` and `ALooper`).

What am I missing? I am suspecting that there are some Android security reasons at play that basically disable the whole mechanism but I have no evidence and I'm just speculating.

It feels that sharing any code wouldn't make any sense as the simple C application is working on adb shell so I think I got this part right.

I am trying this out on a Pixel 6 with Android 12. The C++ library for Android is compiled with sdk version 26 and ndk version 24.0.8215888